# Javascript code for scroll effect works in Safari/chrome, not firefox/opera

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, scrolltop

I have a webpage with a nav bar that initially exists 75px or so below the top of the page. I wrote a script that will fix the nav bar to the top of the browser window when the nav bar hits the top of the browser window. This works fine in safari/chrome, but the effect is not triggered in other browsers. The bar is never switched to its fixed mode. I'm new to html/css/javascript so the problem may be simple. Here is the code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo_css.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function window_onload() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll",navbar_reset_top,false);
}

var navbar_top=75;

function navbar_reset_top() {
    var scrollTop=document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop;
    if(scrollTop>navbar_top&&nav.className==="navbar_absolute") {
        document.getElementById("nav").className="navbar_fixed";
    } 
    else if(scrollTop<navbar_top&&nav.className==="navbar_fixed") {
        document.getElementById("nav").className="navbar_absolute";
    }
 }
 </script>

 </head>
 <body onload="javascript:window_onload();">
 <div id="nav" class="navbar_absolute">
 <ul>
```

And this is all the relevant css I think:

```
#nav.navbar_fixed {
     position:fixed;
     top:0px;
}

#nav.navbar_absolute {
     position:absolute;
     top:74px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version that should work in Firefox.

```
  var nav, navbar_top = 75;
  function window_onload() {
      nav = document.getElementById("nav");
      window.addEventListener("scroll", navbar_reset_top, false);
  }

  function navbar_reset_top() {

      var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

      // you won't need the && nav.className==="navbar_absolute" part
      if(scrollTop > navbar_top && nav.className==="navbar_absolute") {
          nav.className="navbar_fixed";
      }
      // you don't need the check for nav.className==="navbar_fixed" part either
      else if(scrollTop < navbar_top && nav.className==="navbar_fixed") {
          nav.className="navbar_absolute";
      }
   }
```